# lightning:dualListbox inside Lightning:recordEditForm refreshes the entire form on change of option to select values

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, multi-select

When selecting the list of option from available options in (`lightning:dualListbox`) and move/push them to the selected options box or list. The entire component (`lightning:recordEditForm`) gets refreshed. Not sure stop the refresh of parent component and do a custom handle function to save the selected option values inside the `lightning:recordEditForm`

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="aacountIntialization" implements="force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <!-- Attributes -->
   <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" />
   <aura:attribute name="arraySelected" type="String[]" />
   <aura:attribute name="listOptions" type="List" default="[]"/>
   <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editscreen" recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Account">
      <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="neutral" label="Save" iconPosition="right" type="submit"/>
      <lightning:dualListbox aura:id="multipleselectOptions" name="MultiSelectOptions" label="States" 
                       sourceLabel="Available Options" 
                       selectedLabel="Selected Options" 
                       options="{! v.listOptions }"
                       value="{! v.arraySelected }" onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
   </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
handleChange : function (component, event, helper) {
   var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
   helper.arrayToMultistring(selectedOptionValue);
}
```

**Helper**

```
arrayToMultistring: function(selectedOptionValue){
    var array = selectedOptionValue;
    var str = "";
    if(array.length>0){
        for(var i in array){
            console.log(array[i]);
            str=str+array[i]+";";
        }
    }
    component.set("v.arraySelected",str);
}
```

Comment: How’s your helper function implemented?

Comment: @JayantDas updated my question with helper component

Comment: What exactly you mean when you say entire component is refreshed? You don’t have any other attribute except for the duallist and the button. What’s the behavior, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: `lightning:recordEditForm` has few more tags like `lightning:inputField`, where i am directly saving all those fields on `lightning:button type="submit"`. But when i have a `lightning:dualListbox` the entire recordeditform gets refresh when you move the selected options from left box to right

Comment: Your code does not seem to be complete. You don't have a reference of *component* in your helper, whereas you are still using it there. Are you sure this is your complete code? Using *dualListBox* does not refresh the component, you must have something which is causing this refresh.

Comment: @JayantDas dualListbox is doing an auto submit of recordEditForm the moment you click on the right arrow where you move the picklist values

Comment: I understand the issue you are facing, but this is not how it behaves, I verified this by implementing one and it works as expected. Your code does not look to be in its completeness here, so its difficult to identify the cause. E.g., you don't have your complete component, your call to helper method does not pass a reference of component (*helper.arrayToMultistring(selectedOptionValue)*) , and your helper uses it to set the attribute values (*component.set("v.arraySelected",str)*) which should give error. Unless you post near complete code, it will be difficult to provide any opinion here.

Comment: Use my component if this persists. Plus my one has drag and drop! https://github.com/rapsacnz/DualSelect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed with summer'18 Release of Salesforce.[Salesforce issue reported here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000019QImQAM)

Comment: If you could link to any release notes that would greatly improve this answer.